# Download video from wepage

Tags: video, embed

we have a retail store and would like to get videos from the brands websites in order to publish them on our facebook page to show customers.

But we are unable to find the source of the video. It's been many days without being able to find a solution.

here attached is an example of a page with a video in it:
http://www.adidas.gr/supernova-tko-jacket/B28261.html

Thank You very much for the help

Comment: If your problem is a programming question, please state it clearly. What exactly are you trying to achieve, and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I don't think it is about programming. Although I answered, I already flagged it for moderator intervention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, you could inspect the page's source code with your browser's debugging tools and use the video's source url. However, in the given example this doesn't work since the web server does not allow you to access the source url (http://www.adidas.de/0439c333-6d53-4449-a3e5-3f12b1279779).

A different option is to use a capturing software like Fraps. I managed to record the video player in full screen. Now I could remove the black bars on both sides with little work in a video editing software and voilà there you have it.

However, please note that it is illegal to download the videos and reuse them for your purpose as the brands hold the rights of them. As you would have to ask for permission anyways you could also ask them to provide the original video files to you.

Comment: Hello Julian,
thank you for the feedback.

Actually our first try was to contact directly our area distributors asking for the videos, but there are so many sku's that it would be too much work.

Comment: So did this help you?

Comment: Yes, in a way it helped to understand that we cannot do it.
Thank You!